# Postgres existing column doesn't exist error

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have next trouble on db query sending

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "crossroad_id" of relation "api_accidents" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO api_accidents ("crossroad_id", "datetime_start",...
```

Thought trial and error, I discovered that the error is due to quotes.

I have a base class for db querying, and some child classes, that making queries to different tables. Other child class works without interruptions. Below listed function, that sending query to database.

```py
    def send(self, args):

        query = sql.SQL(self.query).format(
                sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier, self.col_names)),
                sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Placeholder, self.col_names))
            )
        self.cursor.execute(query, args)
```

In the child methods I'm changing only fields `col_names` and `query`, and it works perfectly in other classes.

```py
    query = """INSERT INTO api_accidents ({}) VALUES ({})"""
    col_names = ['crossroad_id', 'datetime_start', 'datetime_stop']
```

Here the such raw query work

```sql
INSERT INTO api_accidents (сrossroad_id, datetime_start, datetime_stop)
    VALUES (1, current_timestamp, NULL)
```

And this one doesn't work

```sql
INSERT INTO api_accidents ("сrossroad_id", "datetime_start", "datetime_stop")
    VALUES (1, current_timestamp, NULL)
```

But standard `sql.SQL` formatting making second query.

Is it might to solve this problem without writing column names manually in query?

**UPDATE**

I checked it again, and found out, that it doesn't depends on quotes. This query works no matter with or without quotes:

```sql
INSERT INTO api_accidents (сrossroad_id, datetime_start, datetime_stop)
    VALUES (1, current_timestamp, NULL);
```

And this one doesn't work at all:

```sql
INSERT INTO api_accidents (crossroad_id, datetime_start, datetime_stop)
    VALUES (1, current_timestamp, NULL);
```

Yes, they're exactly the same. But Postgres don't think so.

**UPDATE 2**

Finally I found out, that when I copy column name from `information_schema.columns`, it works. But when I'm typing name of that column by myself, it doesn't work. What it depends on - I don't know.

Comment: You'll need to show your `sql.Identifier` function.

Comment: @DanielRoseman `sql.Identifier` class from `psycopg2.sql` library, that formatting list elements in query. It's not my own.

Comment: what is this question about? i realized ur question has changed over time..

Comment: @Mox now I have only one question: how to make this work every time? Not only when Postgres wants

Comment: i suggest that you update ur question title/content to reflect what you are really asking

Comment: Are you perfectly sure that the queries are run on the same database?

Comment: @klin ofcourse. From one console, connected to one database, same queries returning different results. At least, I found out, that when I copy column name from `information_schema.columns`, it works. But when I'm typing name of that column by myself, it doesn't work. What it depends on - I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result, it turned out that second developer, when creating the table, wrote Cyrillic `c` on column `crossroad_id` instead of Latin...

Fixed by changing column name.